# Range of sum of two trig functions

Tags: functions

How would you find the range of $|\sin x| + |\cos x|$ theoretically and not graphically?

Comment: Are you asking for the range of $|\sin x| + |\cos x|$?

Comment: yes, exactly samuel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Square it.

Let $|\sin x| + |\cos x| = y$

$y^2 = \sin^2x + \cos^2x + |2\sin x \cos x| = 1 + |\sin2x|$

Since $1 \leq 1 + |\sin2x| \leq 2$, just take the square root of this to get $1 \leq y \leq \sqrt 2$

And graphically (just for completeness): http://fooplot.com/#W3sidHlwZSI6MCwiZXEiOiJhYnMoc2luKHgpKSthYnMoY29zKHgpKSIsImNvbG9yIjoiIzAwMDAwMCJ9LHsidHlwZSI6MTAwMH1d